# error occurs when using asycio loop in tornado under high concurrency

Tags: python, tornado, python-asyncio

I installed the `asyncio` `Ioloop` in `tornado` project, it ran with no problem with a single request, but when I did server stress test:

```
ab -n 10000 -c 4000  -p '/home/mwh/ad_tornado/for_test/task.json' -T 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' '192.168.1.170/hwSdk/tsk/get_t_k.json'
```

It happened errors:

```
[E 161216 10:32:22 base_events:1090] Exception in callback BaseAsyncIOLoop._handle_events(11, 1)
handle: <Handle BaseAsyncIOLoop._handle_events(11, 1)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/asyncio/events.py", line 125, in _run
  File "/home/mwh/virtualenv_mwh/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 114, in _handle_events
  File "/home/mwh/virtualenv_mwh/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
  File "/home/mwh/virtualenv_mwh/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 260, in accept_handler
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 187, in accept
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

Is that  use with asynico ioloop in tornado  will degrade the performance?

Comment: I think you ran out of available sockets... Which, if that's the case, you have to do things a little bit more synchronously... Is your python script acting as a client? If that's the case, then you're not testing server "stress" - it's a client issue, and that issue will never pop up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to run `4000` parallel requests, which means `4000` opened sockets at the same time.

But usually system limits allows only 1024 opened files by default (try `ulimit -a`).

You could override the limit by `ulimit -n 4096` call.

Comment: I had set the system limits allows 65536 opened files,But it happened the errors like the same. I found that every process only allows 1024 opened files by default,and I ran 4 tornado instance in my test.How to set the process allows opened files as the  Process ID is changed when  I reopen a tornado instance?

Comment: try to follow this tutorial: http://www.nateware.com/linux-network-tuning-for-2013.html#.WFUEgaJ96Rt